# How to scrape Booking.com with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to do a search on booking, and take the price of the first hotel,
as [this](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.it.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaHGIAQGYARS4ARfIARTYAQHoAQH4AQuIAgGoAgO4AuKiv-sFwAIB&sid=67dc191d6bef3cf8338e8984656795c0&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.it.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaHGIAQGYARS4ARfIARTYAQHoAQH4AQuIAgGoAgO4AuKiv-sFwAIB%3Bsid%3D67dc191d6bef3cf8338e8984656795c0%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=Miami+Beach%2C+Florida%2C+Stati+Uniti&is_ski_area=&ssne=Milano&ssne_untouched=Milano&checkin_monthday=9&checkin_month=11&checkin_year=2019&checkout_monthday=16&checkout_month=11&checkout_year=2019&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1&search_pageview_id=1348697162ef016b&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&ac_suggestion_theme_list_length=0&ac_position=0&ac_langcode=it&ac_click_type=b&dest_id=20023182&dest_type=city&place_id_lat=25.7903&place_id_lon=-80.130302&search_pageview_id=1348697162ef016b&search_selected=true&ss_raw=Miami&order=).

[The screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/k3wBRWF/Cattura.png)

This is the part of the code that interests me

```html
<div class="prco-ltr-right-align-helper">
<div class="bui-price-display__value prco-inline-block-maker-helper" aria-hidden="true">
€&nbsp;702
</div>
<span class="bui-u-sr-only">
Prezzo
€&nbsp;702
</span>
</div>
```

This is my simple code in python

```py
import requests
main_url = the link above
req = requests.get(main_url)
text = req.text
print(text.find('bui-u-sr-only'))
print(text.find('bui-price-display__value prco-inline-block-maker-helper'))
```

The two strings you're looking for are not present, why?

Comment: That site appears to be loaded asynchronously, meaning that the full page doesn't load all at the same time. You may need browser automation like Selenium to access it.

Comment: Try chrome headless option along with selenium.

Comment: This looks like what you're trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448994/wait-page-to-load-before-getting-data-with-requests-get-in-python-3