# Trying to scrape data stored in table using BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from this table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCeYT.jpg)
and here's the code I'm using

```
## Scraping data for schools
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#List of schools
page=urlopen('https://mcss.knack.com/school-districts#all-school-contacts/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

School=[]
Address=[]
Phone=[]
Principal=[]
Email=[]
District=[]

# Indexing rows and then identifying cells
for rows in soup.findAll('tr'):
    cells = rows.findAll('td')
    if len(cells)==7:
        School.append(soup.find("span", {'class':'col-0'}).text)
        Address.append(soup.find("span", {'class':'col-1'}).text)
        Phone.append(soup.find("span", {'class':'col-2'}).text)
        Principal.append(soup.find("span", {'class':'col-3'}).text)
        Email.append(soup.find("span", {'class':'col-4'}).text)
        District.append(soup.find("span", {'class':'col-5'}).text)

import pandas as pd
school_frame = pd.DataFrame({'School' : School,
                           'Address' : Address,
                           'Phone':Phone,
                           'Principal':Principal,
                           'Email':Email,
                           'District':District
                            })

school_frame.head()
#school_frame.to_csv('school_address.csv')
```

And in return I'm getting only the header names of the columns of data frame.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),  Your posting depends on a volatile, off-site image, rather than being self-contained.  Also, you've neglected to reduce this to a minimum: is the problem with the initial `findAll`, the filtering on each record, or the data frame formation?

Answer (score 0):

When you check the actual value of `page`, you will see that it does not contain any table but an empty div which will later be filled by javascript dynamically. `urllib.request` does not run the javascript and just returns an empty page with no table to you. You could use selenium to emulate a browser (which runs javascript) and then fetch the resulting html of that website (see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45451208/9144990) for an example).