# Empty html tags after scraping on the page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the site:

http://finance.sina.com.cn/futures/quotes/I0.shtml?from=wap

To capture the variation of Chinese iron ore:

[image]

After scraping, I search for the tag and find everything empty ' -- '

I'm using:

```
url2 = 'http://finance.sina.com.cn/futures/quotes/I0.shtml?from=wap'
html2 = urlopen(url2)
bs2 = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'lxml')
print(bs2.title)

print(bs2.find_all('span', class_ = 'amt'))
```

output:

```
<title>铁矿石2005(I0)期货行情,新闻,报价_新浪财经_新浪网</title>
[<span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>, <span class="amt">--</span>,.....
```

I already opened the browser console to find out what other pages the site was calling, and found these two:

http://hq.sinajs.cn/?_=1584562106303/&list=sz002578,sz002082,sz002167,sz002501,sh600432,sh600255,sz002160,sz002379,sz002428,sh600311,nf_RB2005,nf_I2005,nf_P2005,nf_M2009,nf_Y2005,nf_JD2005,nf_FU2005,nf_BU2006,hf_CAD,hf_CL,hf_GC,hf_SI,hf_S,hf_BO,hf_C,hf_W,hf_AHD,hf_OIL,nf_I0,nf_I2005

http://hq.sinajs.cn/?_=1584562106303/&list=nf_I0

but nothing to find the variation of the asset ..... (+ 0.16%)

can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: I think that's because `0.16%` is not really there when the web page first loaded, it generated dynamically by javascript and as far as I know `BeautifulSoup` couldn't handle such a case. You can look the answer to this question --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448994/wait-page-to-load-before-getting-data-with-requests-get-in-python-3

Comment: Put this as an answer, it solved my problem

Comment: Great! I am glad to hear that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because `0.16%` is not really there when the web page first loaded.

It generated dynamically by javascript and as far as I know `BeautifulSoup` couldn't handle such a case.

You can look the answer similar to this problem in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448994/wait-page-to-load-before-getting-data-with-requests-get-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Selenium. It's slower but it will work
See selenium docs  https://www.selenium.dev/