# How to get html from scraped script data?

Tags: javascript, python

I have scraped a website using the following code:

```
import requests

url = "https://jobs.51job.com/beijing/we03/p1000/"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-HK;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,an;q=0.5,zh-TW;q=0.4',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Cookie': '_uab_collina=165942422997031185893743; guid=eb82eddafe61ebf8230a4198f833ae79; nsearch=jobarea%3D%26%7C%26ord_field%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch0%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch1%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch2%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch3%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch4%3D%26%7C%26collapse_expansion%3D; sensorsdata2015jssdkcross=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%22eb82eddafe61ebf8230a4198f833ae79%22%2C%22first_id%22%3A%2218257038d65902-00814c9fd9cb0b5-26021a51-2359296-18257038d66448%22%2C%22props%22%3A%7B%22%24latest_traffic_source_type%22%3A%22%E7%9B%B4%E6%8E%A5%E6%B5%81%E9%87%8F%22%2C%22%24latest_search_keyword%22%3A%22%E6%9C%AA%E5%8F%96%E5%88%B0%E5%80%BC_%E7%9B%B4%E6%8E%A5%E6%89%93%E5%BC%80%22%2C%22%24latest_referrer%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22identities%22%3A%22eyIkaWRlbnRpdHlfY29va2llX2lkIjoiMTgyNTcwMzhkNjU5MDItMDA4MTRjOWZkOWNiMGI1LTI2MDIxYTUxLTIzNTkyOTYtMTgyNTcwMzhkNjY0NDgiLCIkaWRlbnRpdHlfbG9naW5faWQiOiJlYjgyZWRkYWZlNjFlYmY4MjMwYTQxOThmODMzYWU3OSJ9%22%2C%22history_login_id%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22%24identity_login_id%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22eb82eddafe61ebf8230a4198f833ae79%22%7D%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%2218257038d65902-00814c9fd9cb0b5-26021a51-2359296-18257038d66448%22%7D; privacy=1659421937; search=jobarea%7E%60000000%7C%21ord_field%7E%601%7C%21recentSearch0%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0000%A1%FB%A1%FA00%A1%FB%A1%FA02%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA05%A1%FB%A1%FA05%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA1%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21recentSearch1%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0000%A1%FB%A1%FA00%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA05%A1%FB%A1%FA05%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA1%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21recentSearch2%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0000%A1%FB%A1%FA00%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA06%A1%FB%A1%FA05%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA1%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21recentSearch3%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0000%A1%FB%A1%FA00%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA07%A1%FB%A1%FA05%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA1%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21recentSearch4%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0000%A1%FB%A1%FA00%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA07%A1%FB%A1%FA03%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA1%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21collapse_expansion%7E%601%7C%21; acw_tc=ac11000116594238560812054e00dff69255f53eeca27179c31d9ea4800a4f; acw_sc__v2=62e8cc702340c2244fcf4b283cf913fd254d0022; ssxmod_itna=euGQDILDC3ql4iuB=D9DfxmTjG5dDyGoFaeax0yD9qiODUxn4iaDTZY56ClGB1iW3Q5DQTP=YFPl03irbEE7AWzbokGIjbnlD0aDbqF24IzDYYDtxBYDQxAYDGDDpcDzutGuD0IdDje5DFxi1Mx08DeKQ2=DDUWiw5iv=DC57D7KDnOqDAhYDmg4DRP5Deg4D9xKDwgRmq4G7DAyA9xi3n1DDBpi4DQnxp/I6947p7UEvhbSv+4Kfw8k3yEHs2xib0j8wnr=sU7LNi1RqZ00q7jbrG0hrFG+x5erYderrFirr8GxrBVtPWA5xeDi=Gqe03YD; ssxmod_itna2=euGQDILDC3ql4iuB=D9DfxmTjG5dDyGoFaexnK30QqrDlPfExj4re=Fhckx6sAH7/rk2LantiTTNkn4+u5TdniKmSG+418Qey7e=U0oux3x/8CFwILUelS63=+adRjx5tVPUZWZvnkwEWi6EeTcjH+NZ+hXrD=Dn4b+oOCceozEPYTzrY7O/Kah8mzQSgkZEpfaKH1nZcL0OvTH2osczWGK1yk/j5t2Zdwqun0PUkTMaCwxzruvxTFst6FaNDR3ZlclW=kxUbxXeg0Q7WmBeSD7Q/Ab=tfvNKg8PgA8KoIX5gl2pOFTfzi+zvuDbR3wuPb8YQoTzobqoYmkYgM=TboalCLG+6r+kWbcAhLBhz2wWnd8eGQCCPDoxW+PBhBAht7h4CWYQTEkYPeGygDon5imrORplQhfWG7mbYZG4npBBCWe=O8EFCGW4PD7QG4GcDG75iDD=; guid=dfed6851f35e3386f20279eac6d274df; nsearch=jobarea%3D%26%7C%26ord_field%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch0%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch1%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch2%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch3%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch4%3D%26%7C%26collapse_expansion%3D; search=jobarea%7E%60000000%7C%21ord_field%7E%600%7C%21recentSearch0%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0202%A1%FB%A1%FA37%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA1%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21recentSearch1%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0202%A1%FB%A1%FA01%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA1%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21recentSearch2%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0000%A1%FB%A1%FA00%A1%FB%A1%FA01%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA01%A1%FB%A1%FA04%A1%FB%A1%FA08%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA01%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA1%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21recentSearch3%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0000%A1%FB%A1%FA00%A1%FB%A1%FA01%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA01%A1%FB%A1%FA04%A1%FB%A1%FA04%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA01%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA1%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21recentSearch4%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0000%A1%FB%A1%FA00%A1%FB%A1%FA01%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA06%A1%FB%A1%FA01%A1%FB%A1%FA02%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA02%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA1%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21',
  'DNT': '1',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
  'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I expect to get the html code of https://jobs.51job.com/beijing/we03/p1000/

However, I got the following:

```
<html>
<script>
    var arg1='759F9F39A9435F537AE8EBC86B15E2F2C821674D';
var _0x4818=['\x63\x73\x4b\x48\x77\x71\x4d\x49','\x5a\x73\x4b\x4a\x77\x72\x38\x56\x65\x41\x73\x79','\x55\x63\x4b\x69\x4e\x38\x4f\x2f\x77\x70\x6c\x77\x4d\x41\x3d\x3d','\x4a\x52\x38\x43\x54\x67\x3d\x3d','\x59\x73\x4f\x6e\x62\x53\x45\x51\x77\x37\x6f\x7a\x77\x71\x5a\x4b\x65\x73\x4b\x55\x77\x37\x6b\x77\x58\x38\x4f\x52\x49\x51\x3d\x3d','\x77\x37\x6f\x56\x53\x38\x4f\x53\x77\x6f\x50\x43\x6c\x33\x6a\x43\x68\x4d\x4b\x68\x77\x36\x48\x44\x6c\x73\x4b\x58\x77\x34\x73\x2f\x59\x73\x4f\x47','\x66\x77\x56\x6d\x49\x31\x41\x74\x77\x70\x6c\x61\x59\x38\x4f\x74\x77\x35\x63\x4e\x66\x53\x67\x70\x77\x36\x4d\x3d','\x4f\x63\x4f\x4e\x77\x72\x6a\x43\x71\x73\x4b\x78\x54\x47\x54\x43\x68\x73\x4f\x6a\x45\x57\x45\x38\x50\x63\x4f\x63\x4a\x38\x4b\x36','\x55\x38\x4b\x35\x4c\x63\x4f\x74\x77\x70\x56\x30\x45\x4d\x4f\x6b\x77\x34\x37\x44\x72\x4d\x4f\x58','\x48\x4d\x4f\x32\x77\x6f\x48\x43\x69\x4d\x4b\x39\x53\x6c\x58\x43\x6c\x63\x4f\x6f\x43\x31\x6b\x3d','\x61\x73\x4b\x49\x77\x71\x4d\x44\x64\x67\x4d\x75\x50\x73\x4f\x4b\x42\x4d\x4b\x63\x77\x72\x72\x43\x74\x6b\x4c\x44\x72\x4d\x4b\x42\x77\x36\x34\x64','\x77\x71\x49\x6d\x4d\x54\x30\x74\x77\x36\x52\x4e\x77\x35\x6b\x3d','\x44\x4d\x4b\x63\x55\x30\x4a\x6d\x55\x77\x55\x76','\x56\x6a\x48\x44\x6c\x4d\x4f\x48\x56\x63\x4f\x4e\x58\x33\x66\x44\x69\x63\x4b\x4a\x48\x51\x3d\x3d','\x77\x71\x68\x42\x48\x38\x4b\x6e\x77\x34\x54\x44\x68\x53\x44\x44\x67\x4d\x4f\x64\x77\x72\x6a\x43\x6e\x63\x4f\x57\x77\x70\x68\x68\x4e\x38\x4b\x43\x47\x63\x4b\x71\x77\x36\x64\x48\x41\x55\x35\x2b\x77\x72\x67\x32\x4a\x63\x4b\x61\x77\x34\x49\x45\x4a\x63\x4f\x63\x77\x72\x52\x4a\x77\x6f\x5a\x30\x77\x71\x46\x39\x59\x67\x41\x56','\x64\x7a\x64\x32\x77\x35\x62\x44\x6d\x33\x6a\x44\x70\x73\x4b\x33\x77\x70\x59\x3d','\x77\x34\x50\x44\x67\x63\x4b\x58\x77\x6f\x33\x43\x6b\x63\x4b\x4c\x77\x72\x35\x71\x77\x72\x59\x3d','\x77\x72\x4a\x4f\x54\x63\x4f\x51\x57\x4d\x4f\x67','\x77\x71\x54\x44\x76\x63\x4f\x6a\x77\x34\x34\x37\x77\x72\x34\x3d','\x77\x35\x58\x44\x71\x73\x4b\x68\x4d\x46\x31\x2f','\x77\x72\x41\x79\x48\x73\x4f\x66\x77\x70\x70\x63','\x4a\x33\x64\x56\x50\x63\x4f\x78\x4c\x67\x3d\x3d','\x77\x72\x64\x48\x77\x37\x70\x39\x5a\x77\x3d\x3d','\x77\x34\x72\x44\x6f\x38\x4b\x6d\x4e\x45\x77\x3d','\x49\x4d\x4b\x41\x55\x6b\x42\x74','\x77\x36\x62\x44\x72\x63\x4b\x51\x77\x70\x56\x48\x77\x70\x4e\x51\x77\x71\x55\x3d','\x64\x38\x4f\x73\x57\x68\x41\x55\x77\x37\x59\x7a\x77\x72\x55\x3d','\x77\x71\x6e\x43\x6b\x73\x4f\x65\x65\x7a\x72\x44\x68\x77\x3d\x3d','\x55\x73\x4b\x6e\x49\x4d\x4b\x57\x56\x38\x4b\x2f','\x77\x34\x7a\x44\x6f\x63\x4b\x38\x4e\x55\x5a\x76','\x63\x38\x4f\x78\x5a\x68\x41\x4a\x77\x36\x73\x6b\x77\x71\x4a\x6a','\x50\x63\x4b\x49\x77\x34\x6e\x43\x6b\x6b\x56\x62','\x4b\x48\x67\x6f\x64\x4d\x4f\x32\x56\x51\x3d\x3d','\x77\x70\x73\x6d\x77\x71\x76\x44\x6e\x47\x46\x71','\x77\x71\x4c\x44\x74\x38\x4f\x6b\x77\x34\x63\x3d','\x77\x37\x77\x31\x77\x34\x50\x43\x70\x73\x4f\x34\x77\x71\x41\x3d','\x77\x71\x39\x46\x52\x73\x4f\x71\x57\x4d\x4f\x71','\x62\x79\x42\x68\x77\x37\x72\x44\x6d\x33\x34\x3d','\x4c\x48\x67\x2b\x53\x38\x4f\x74\x54\x77\x3d\x3d','\x77\x71\x68\x4f\x77\x37\x31\x35\x64\x73\x4f\x48','\x55\x38\x4f\x37\x56\x73\x4f\x30\x77\x71\x76\x44\x76\x63\x4b\x75\x4b\x73\x4f\x71\x58\x38\x4b\x72','\x59\x69\x74\x74\x77\x35\x44\x44\x6e\x57\x6e\x44\x72\x41\x3d\x3d','\x59\x4d\x4b\x49\x77\x71\x55\x55\x66\x67\x49\x6b','\x61\x42\x37\x44\x6c\x4d\x4f\x44\x54\x51\x3d\x3d','\x77\x70\x66\x44\x68\x38\x4f\x72\x77\x36\x6b\x6b','\x77\x37\x76\x43\x71\x4d\x4f\x72\x59\x38\x4b\x41\x56\x6b\x35\x4f\x77\x70\x6e\x43\x75\x38\x4f\x61\x58\x73\x4b\x5a\x50\x33\x44\x43\x6c\x63\x4b\x79\x77\x36\x48\x44\x72\x51\x3d\x3d','\x77\x6f\x77\x2b\x77\x36\x76\x44\x6d\x48\x70\x73\x77\x37\x52\x74\x77\x6f\x39\x38\x4c\x43\x37\x43\x69\x47\x37\x43\x6b\x73\x4f\x52\x54\x38\x4b\x6c\x57\x38\x4f\x35\x77\x72\x33\x44\x69\x38\x4f\x54\x48\x73\x4f\x44\x65\x48\x6a\x44\x6d\x63\x4b\x6c\x4a\x73\x4b\x71\x56\x41\x3d\x3d','\x4e\x77\x56\x2b','\x77\x37\x48\x44\x72\x63\x4b\x74\x77\x70\x4a\x61\x77\x70\x5a\x62','\x77\x70\x51\x73\x77\x71\x76\x44\x69\x48\x70\x75\x77\x36\x49\x3d','\x59\x4d\x4b\x55\x77\x71\x4d\x4a\x5a\x51\x3d\x3d','\x4b\x48\x31\x56\x4b\x63\x4f\x71\x4b\x73\x4b\x31','\x66\x51\x35\x73\x46\x55\x6b\x6b\x77\x70\x49\x3d','\x77\x72\x76\x43\x72\x63\x4f\x42\x52\x38\x4b\x6b','\x4d\x33\x77\x30\x66\x51\x3d\x3d','\x77\x36\x78\x58\x77\x71\x50\x44\x76\x4d\x4f\x46\x77\x6f\x35\x64'];(function(_0x4c97f0,_0x1742fd){var _0x4db1c=function(_0x48181e){while(--_0x48181e){_0x4c97f0['\x70\x75\x73\x68'](_0x4c97f0['\x73\x68\x69\x66\x74']());}};var _0x3cd6c6=function(){var _0xb8360b={'\x64\x61\x74\x61':{'\x6b\x65\x79':'\x63\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65','\x76\x61\x6c\x75\x65':'\x74\x69\x6d\x65\x6f\x75\x74'},'\x73\x65\x74\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65':function(_0x20bf34,_0x3e840e,_0x5693d3,_0x5e8b26){_0x5e8b26=_0x5e8b26||{};var _0xba82f0=_0x3e840e+'\x3d'+_0x5693d3;var _0x5afe31=0x0;for(var _0x5afe31=0x0,_0x178627=_0x20bf34['\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68'];_0x5afe31<_0x178627;_0x5afe31++){var _0x41b2ff=_0x20bf34[_0x5afe31];_0xba82f0+='\x3b\x20'+_0x41b2ff;var _0xd79219=_0x20bf34[_0x41b2ff];_0x20bf34['\x70\x75\x73\x68'](_0xd79219);_0x178627=_0x20bf34['\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68'];if(_0xd79219!==!![]){_0xba82f0+='\x3d'+_0xd79219;}}_0x5e8b26['\x63\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65']=_0xba82f0;},'\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65':function(){return'\x64\x65\x76';},'\x67\x65\x74\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65':function(_0x4a11fe,_0x189946){_0x4a11fe=_0x4a11fe||function(_0x6259a2){return _0x6259a2;};var _0x25af93=_0x4a11fe(new RegExp('\x28\x3f\x3a\x5e\x7c\x3b\x20\x29'+_0x189946['\x72\x65\x70\x6c\x61\x63\x65'](/([.$?*|{}()[]\/+^])/g,'\x24\x31')+'\x3d\x28\x5b\x5e\x3b\x5d\x2a\x29'));var _0x52d57c=function(_0x105f59,_0x3fd789){_0x105f59(++_0x3fd789);};_0x52d57c(_0x4db1c,_0x1742fd);return _0x25af93?decodeURIComponent(_0x25af93[0x1]):undefined;}};var _0x4a2aed=function(){var _0x124d17=new RegExp('\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5c\x28\x5c\x29\x20\x2a\x7b\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x2e\x2b\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x3b\x3f\x20\x2a\x7d');return _0x124d17['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](_0xb8360b['\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65']['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67']());};_0xb8360b['\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65']=_0x4a2aed;var _0x2d67ec='';var _0x120551=_0xb8360b['\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65']();if(!_0x120551){_0xb8360b['\x73\x65\x74\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65'](['\x2a'],'\x63\x6f\x75\x6e\x74\x65\x72',0x1);}else if(_0x120551){_0x2d67ec=_0xb8360b['\x67\x65\x74\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65'](null,'\x63\x6f\x75\x6e\x74\x65\x72');}else{_0xb8360b['\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65']();}};_0x3cd6c6();}(_0x4818,0x15b));var _0x55f3=function(_0x4c97f0,_0x1742fd){var _0x4c97f0=parseInt(_0x4c97f0,0x10);var _0x48181e=_0x4818[_0x4c97f0];if(!_0x55f3['\x61\x74\x6f\x62\x50\x6f\x6c\x79\x66\x69\x6c\x6c\x41\x70\x70\x65\x6e\x64\x65\x64']){(function(){var _0xdf49c6=Function('\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x28\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x20\x28\x29\x20'+'\x7b\x7d\x2e\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72\x28\x22\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x22\x29\x28\x29'+'\x29\x3b');var _0xb8360b=_0xdf49c6();var _0x389f44='\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x2b\x2f\x3d';_0xb8360b['\x61\x74\x6f\x62']||(_0xb8360b['\x61\x74\x6f\x62']=function(_0xba82f0){var _0xec6bb4=String(_0xba82f0)['\x72\x65\x70\x6c\x61\x63\x65'](/=+$/,'');for(var _0x1a0f04=0x0,_0x18c94e,_0x41b2ff,_0xd79219=0x0,_0x5792f7='';_0x41b2ff=_0xec6bb4['\x63\x68\x61\x72\x41\x74'](_0xd79219++);~_0x41b2ff&&(_0x18c94e=_0x1a0f04%0x4?_0x18c94e*0x40+_0x41b2ff:_0x41b2ff,_0x1a0f04++%0x4)?_0x5792f7+=String['\x66\x72\x6f\x6d\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6f\x64\x65'](0xff&_0x18c94e>>(-0x2*_0x1a0f04&0x6)):0x0){_0x41b2ff=_0x389f44['\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66'](_0x41b2ff);}return _0x5792f7;});}());_0x55f3['\x61\x74\x6f\x62\x50\x6f\x6c\x79\x66\x69\x6c\x6c\x41\x70\x70\x65\x6e\x64\x65\x64']=!![];}if(!_0x55f3['\x72\x63\x34']){var _0x232678=function(_0x401af1,_0x532ac0){var _0x45079a=[],_0x52d57c=0x0,_0x105f59,_0x3fd789='',_0x4a2aed='';_0x401af1=atob(_0x401af1);for(var _0x124d17=0x0,_0x1b9115=_0x401af1['\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68'];_0x124d17<_0x1b9115;_0x124d17++){_0x4a2aed+='\x25'+('\x30\x30'+_0x401af1['\x63\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6f\x64\x65\x41\x74'](_0x124d17)['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67'](0x10))['\x73\x6c\x69\x63\x65'](-0x2);}_0x401af1=decodeURIComponent(_0x4a2aed);for(var _0x2d67ec=0x0;_0x2d67ec<0x100;_0x2d67ec++){_0x45079a[_0x2d67ec]=_0x2d67ec;}for(_0x2d67ec=0x0;_0x2d67ec<0x100;_0x2d67ec++){_0x52d57c=(_0x52d57c+_0x45079a[_0x2d67ec]+_0x532ac0['\x63\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6f\x64\x65\x41\x74'](_0x2d67ec%_0x532ac0['\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68']))%0x100;_0x105f59=_0x45079a[_0x2d67ec];_0x45079a[_0x2d67ec]=_0x45079a[_0x52d57c];_0x45079a[_0x52d57c]=_0x105f59;}_0x2d67ec=0x0;_0x52d57c=0x0;for(var _0x4e5ce2=0x0;_0x4e5ce2<_0x401af1['\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68'];_0x4e5ce2++){_0x2d67ec=(_0x2d67ec+0x1)%0x100;_0x52d57c=(_0x52d57c+_0x45079a[_0x2d67ec])%0x100;_0x105f59=_0x45079a[_0x2d67ec];_0x45079a[_0x2d67ec]=_0x45079a[_0x52d57c];_0x45079a[_0x52d57c]=_0x105f59;_0x3fd789+=String['\x66\x72\x6f\x6d\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6f\x64\x65'](_0x401af1['\x63\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6f\x64\x65\x41\x74'](_0x4e5ce2)^_0x45079a[(_0x45079a[_0x2d67ec]+_0x45079a[_0x52d57c])%0x100]);}return _0x3fd789;};_0x55f3['\x72\x63\x34']=_0x232678;}if(!_0x55f3['\x64\x61\x74\x61']){_0x55f3['\x64\x61\x74\x61']={};}if(_0x55f3['\x64\x61\x74\x61'][_0x4c97f0]===undefined){if(!_0x55f3['\x6f\x6e\x63\x65']){var _0x5f325c=function(_0x23a392){this['\x72\x63\x34\x42\x79\x74\x65\x73']=_0x23a392;this['\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x73']=[0x1,0x0,0x0];this['\x6e\x65\x77\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65']=function(){return'\x6e\x65\x77\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65';};this['\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65']='\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5c\x28\x5c\x29\x20\x2a\x7b\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a';this['\x73\x65\x63\x6f\x6e\x64\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65']='\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x2e\x2b\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x3b\x3f\x20\x2a\x7d';};_0x5f325c['\x70\x72\x6f\x74\x6f\x74\x79\x70\x65']['\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65']=function(){var _0x19f809=new RegExp(this['\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65']+this['\x73\x65\x63\x6f\x6e\x64\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65']);return this['\x72\x75\x6e\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65'](_0x19f809['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](this['\x6e\x65\x77\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65']['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67']())?--this['\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x73'][0x1]:--this['\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x73'][0x0]);};_0x5f325c['\x70\x72\x6f\x74\x6f\x74\x79\x70\x65']['\x72\x75\x6e\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65']=function(_0x4380bd){if(!Boolean(~_0x4380bd)){return _0x4380bd;}return this['\x67\x65\x74\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65'](this['\x72\x63\x34\x42\x79\x74\x65\x73']);};_0x5f325c['\x70\x72\x6f\x74\x6f\x74\x79\x70\x65']['\x67\x65\x74\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65']=function(_0x58d85e){for(var _0x1c9f5b=0x0,_0x1ce9e0=this['\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x73']['\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68'];_0x1c9f5b<_0x1ce9e0;_0x1c9f5b++){this['\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x73']['\x70\x75\x73\x68'](Math['\x72\x6f\x75\x6e\x64'](Math['\x72\x61\x6e\x64\x6f\x6d']()));_0x1ce9e0=this['\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x73']['\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68'];}return _0x58d85e(this['\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x73'][0x0]);};new _0x5f325c(_0x55f3)['\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65']();_0x55f3['\x6f\x6e\x63\x65']=!![];}_0x48181e=_0x55f3['\x72\x63\x34'](_0x48181e,_0x1742fd);_0x55f3['\x64\x61\x74\x61'][_0x4c97f0]=_0x48181e;}else{_0x48181e=_0x55f3['\x64\x61\x74\x61'][_0x4c97f0];}return _0x48181e;};var arg3=null;var arg4=null;var arg5=null;var arg6=null;var arg7=null;var arg8=null;var arg9=null;var arg10=null;var l=function(){while(window[_0x55f3('0x1', '\x58\x4d\x57\x5e')]||window['\x5f\x5f\x70\x68\x61\x6e\x74\x6f\x6d\x61\x73']){};var _0x5e8b26=_0x55f3('0x3', '\x6a\x53\x31\x59');String[_0x55f3('0x5', '\x6e\x5d\x66\x52')][_0x55f3('0x6', '\x50\x67\x35\x34')]=function(_0x4e08d8){var _0x5a5d3b='';for(var _0xe89588=0x0;_0xe89588<this[_0x55f3('0x8', '\x29\x68\x52\x63')]&&_0xe89588<_0x4e08d8[_0x55f3('0xa', '\x6a\x45\x26\x5e')];_0xe89588+=0x2){var _0x401af1=parseInt(this[_0x55f3('0xb', '\x56\x32\x4b\x45')](_0xe89588,_0xe89588+0x2),0x10);var _0x105f59=parseInt(_0x4e08d8[_0x55f3('0xd', '\x58\x4d\x57\x5e')](_0xe89588,_0xe89588+0x2),0x10);var _0x189e2c=(_0x401af1^_0x105f59)[_0x55f3('0xf', '\x57\x31\x46\x45')](0x10);if(_0x189e2c[_0x55f3('0x11', '\x4d\x47\x72\x76')]==0x1){_0x189e2c='\x30'+_0x189e2c;}_0x5a5d3b+=_0x189e2c;}return _0x5a5d3b;};String['\x70\x72\x6f\x74\x6f\x74\x79\x70\x65'][_0x55f3('0x14', '\x5a\x2a\x44\x4d')]=function(){var _0x4b082b=[0xf,0x23,0x1d,0x18,0x21,0x10,0x1,0x26,0xa,0x9,0x13,0x1f,0x28,0x1b,0x16,0x17,0x19,0xd,0x6,0xb,0x27,0x12,0x14,0x8,0xe,0x15,0x20,0x1a,0x2,0x1e,0x7,0x4,0x11,0x5,0x3,0x1c,0x22,0x25,0xc,0x24];var _0x4da0dc=[];var _0x12605e='';for(var _0x20a7bf=0x0;_0x20a7bf<this['\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68'];_0x20a7bf++){var _0x385ee3=this[_0x20a7bf];for(var _0x217721=0x0;_0x217721<_0x4b082b[_0x55f3('0x16', '\x61\x48\x2a\x4e')];_0x217721++){if(_0x4b082b[_0x217721]==_0x20a7bf+0x1){_0x4da0dc[_0x217721]=_0x385ee3;}}}_0x12605e=_0x4da0dc['\x6a\x6f\x69\x6e']('');return _0x12605e;};var _0x23a392=arg1[_0x55f3('0x19', '\x50\x67\x35\x34')]();arg2=_0x23a392[_0x55f3('0x1b', '\x7a\x35\x4f\x26')](_0x5e8b26);setTimeout('\x72\x65\x6c\x6f\x61\x64\x28\x61\x72\x67\x32\x29',0x2);};var _0x4db1c=function(){function _0x355d23(_0x450614){if((''+_0x450614/_0x450614)[_0x55f3('0x1c', '\x56\x32\x4b\x45')]!==0x1||_0x450614%0x14===0x0){(function(){}[_0x55f3('0x1d', '\x43\x4e\x55\x59')]((undefined+'')[0x2]+(!![]+'')[0x3]+([][_0x55f3('0x1e', '\x77\x38\x50\x52')]()+'')[0x2]+(undefined+'')[0x0]+(![]+[0x0]+String)[0x14]+(![]+[0x0]+String)[0x14]+(!![]+'')[0x3]+(!![]+'')[0x1])());}else{(function(){}['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72']((undefined+'')[0x2]+(!![]+'')[0x3]+([][_0x55f3('0x1f', '\x4c\x24\x28\x44')]()+'')[0x2]+(undefined+'')[0x0]+(![]+[0x0]+String)[0x14]+(![]+[0x0]+String)[0x14]+(!![]+'')[0x3]+(!![]+'')[0x1])());}_0x355d23(++_0x450614);}try{_0x355d23(0x0);}catch(_0x54c483){}};if(function(){var _0x470d8f=function(){var _0x4c97f0=!![];return function(_0x1742fd,_0x4db1c){var _0x48181e=_0x4c97f0?function(){if(_0x4db1c){var _0x55f3be=_0x4db1c['\x61\x70\x70\x6c\x79'](_0x1742fd,arguments);_0x4db1c=null;return _0x55f3be;}}:function(){};_0x4c97f0=![];return _0x48181e;};}();var _0x501fd7=_0x470d8f(this,function(){var _0x4c97f0=function(){return'\x64\x65\x76';},_0x1742fd=function(){return'\x77\x69\x6e\x64\x6f\x77';};var _0x55f3be=function(){var _0x3ad9a1=new RegExp('\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5c\x28\x5c\x29\x20\x2a\x7b\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x2e\x2b\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x3b\x3f\x20\x2a\x7d');return!_0x3ad9a1['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](_0x4c97f0['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67']());};var _0x1b93ad=function(){var _0x20bf34=new RegExp('\x28\x5c\x5c\x5b\x78\x7c\x75\x5d\x28\x5c\x77\x29\x7b\x32\x2c\x34\x7d\x29\x2b');return _0x20bf34['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](_0x1742fd['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67']());};var _0x5afe31=function(_0x178627){var _0x1a0f04=~-0x1>>0x1+0xff%0x0;if(_0x178627['\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66']('\x69'===_0x1a0f04)){_0xd79219(_0x178627);}};var _0xd79219=function(_0x5792f7){var _0x4e08d8=~-0x4>>0x1+0xff%0x0;if(_0x5792f7['\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66']((!![]+'')[0x3])!==_0x4e08d8){_0x5afe31(_0x5792f7);}};if(!_0x55f3be()){if(!_0x1b93ad()){_0x5afe31('\x69\x6e\x64\u0435\x78\x4f\x66');}else{_0x5afe31('\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66');}}else{_0x5afe31('\x69\x6e\x64\u0435\x78\x4f\x66');}});_0x501fd7();var _0x3a394d=function(){var _0x1ab151=!![];return function(_0x372617,_0x42d229){var _0x3b3503=_0x1ab151?function(){if(_0x42d229){var _0x7086d9=_0x42d229[_0x55f3('0x21', '\x4b\x4e\x29\x46')](_0x372617,arguments);_0x42d229=null;return _0x7086d9;}}:function(){};_0x1ab151=![];return _0x3b3503;};}();var _0x5b6351=_0x3a394d(this,function(){var _0x46cbaa=Function(_0x55f3('0x22', '\x26\x68\x5a\x59')+_0x55f3('0x23', '\x61\x48\x2a\x4e')+'\x29\x3b');var _0x1766ff=function(){};var _0x9b5e29=_0x46cbaa();_0x9b5e29[_0x55f3('0x26', '\x61\x48\x2a\x4e')]['\x6c\x6f\x67']=_0x1766ff;_0x9b5e29[_0x55f3('0x29', '\x56\x25\x59\x52')][_0x55f3('0x2a', '\x50\x5e\x45\x71')]=_0x1766ff;_0x9b5e29[_0x55f3('0x2c', '\x6c\x67\x4d\x30')][_0x55f3('0x2d', '\x4c\x24\x28\x44')]=_0x1766ff;_0x9b5e29[_0x55f3('0x2f', '\x43\x5a\x63\x38')][_0x55f3('0x30', '\x57\x75\x36\x25')]=_0x1766ff;});_0x5b6351();try{return!!window['\x61\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74\x4c\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6e\x65\x72'];}catch(_0x35538d){return![];}}()){document[_0x55f3('0x33', '\x56\x25\x59\x52')](_0x55f3('0x34', '\x79\x41\x70\x7a'),l,![]);}else{document[_0x55f3('0x36', '\x79\x41\x70\x7a')](_0x55f3('0x37', '\x4c\x24\x28\x44'),l);}_0x4db1c();setInterval(function(){_0x4db1c();},0xfa0);
        
function setCookie(name,value){var expiredate=new Date();expiredate.setTime(expiredate.getTime()+(3600*1000));document.cookie=name+"="+value+";expires="+expiredate.toGMTString()+";max-age=3600;path=/";}
function reload(x) {setCookie("acw_sc__v2", x);document.location.reload();}
</script>

</html>
```

What should I do the get the html code of the website?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like it's an obfuscated SPA, complicated further by all the unicode characters. The issue is that your GET request is not triggering the JavaScript to actually load the page. You'll need to use a headless browser, or some other setup to get it working. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45451208/1682790) for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parts of the page are loaded dynamically thats why you dont get all the content. I recommend using a tool like a puppeteer and waiting for the network to be idle, which means all scripts got loaded and you can display all HTML as you would see in inspector

install puppeteer:

```
npm i --save puppeteer
```

run the code below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async function main() {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const [page] = await browser.pages();

        await page.goto('https://jobs.51job.com/beijing/we03/p1000/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
        const data = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML);

        console.log(data);

        await browser.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, Karol. Can I use python to do the same procedures?

Comment: Thank you, Jack. Using selenium is a solution.

Comment: for python you can use an equivalent tool which is called pyppeter:
https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/pyppeteer/

mentioned Selenium can be a solution as well.