# I'm Trying To Scrape The Duration Of Tiktok Videos But I am Getting 'None'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request

I want to scrape the duration of tiktok videos for an upcoming project but my code isn't working

```py
import requests; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = requests.get('https://vm.tiktok.com/ZMFFKmx3K/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
data = soup.find('div', class_="tiktok-1g3unbt-DivSeekBarTimeContainer e123m2eu1")
print(data)
```

Using an example tiktok
[image]

I would think this would work could anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn off `JavaScript` then check out the element selection in chrome devtools then you will see that the value is like 00/000 but when you will turn JS and the video is on play mode then the duration is increasing uoto finishig.So the real duration value of that element depends on Js. So you have to use an automation tool something like selenium  to grab that dynamic value. And How much duration will scrape that depend on `time.sleep()` if you are on selenium. If time.sleep is more than the video length then it will show None typEerror.

**Example:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)
url ='https://vm.tiktok.com/ZMFFKmx3K/'

driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(25)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

data = soup.find('div', class_="tiktok-1g3unbt-DivSeekBarTimeContainer e123m2eu1")
print(data.text)
```

**Output:**

```
00:25/00:28
```

Comment: Thank you at first I thought the tab opening was a bad thing but I found a ways to implement it, Thank you so much May god bless you

Comment: @Fazlul , Can you guide me in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74000302/8519380

Answer (score 1):

the ID associated is likely randomized. Try using regex to get element by class ending in 'TimeContainer' + some other id

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
content = requests.get('https://vm.tiktok.com/ZMFFKmx3K/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
data = soup.find('div', {'class': re.compile(r'TimeContainer.*$')})
print(data)
```

you next issue is that the page loads before the video, so you'll get 0/0 for the time. try [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) instead so you can add timer waits for loading

Comment: i still get None i dont even get 0/0

Comment: not sure why. i get ```<div class="tiktok-1g3unbt-DivSeekBarTimeContainer e123m2eu1">00:00/00:00</div>```

Comment: mm uh.......umm

Comment: you'll run into the 0/0 issue anyway, so try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45451208/11616708) approach